# force HTTPS on Google Cloud Endpoints + App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a web service running on Google App Engine with Cloud Endpoints for security. My web service is running on node.js with express. I have:

```
schemes:
- "https"
```

in my openAPI swagger file but the paths still works with HTTP. I want to make the web service SSL only. How can I block all HTTP requests?

Modifying the app.yaml doesn't work for me because node.js environment doesn't support handlers. I tried using the [express-sslify module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify) but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints does not have the ability to block requests according to the scheme. Therefore, you cannot use Endpoints to perform blocking only HTTP requests.

Comment: do you know a proper way to disable HTTP requests? Checking for headers in app engine server doesn't work for me